# Error: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException. How fix it ?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jetty

I have a problem with my project. When i sumbmit `UserForm` to save a `User` then occur a following error:

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required
>   type java.util.Date for property birthDay; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type java.lang.String to type java.util.Date for value
>   2016-03-26; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Here file UserForm.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>         
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add New User</title>
    </head>
<body>
<h2>Please Input User Information</h2>

    <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="User" action="/user/save">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="userName">UserName</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="userName"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="userName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="passWord">Password</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="passWord"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="passWord" /></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="birthDay">Birthday</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="birthDay" type = "date"/> </td>

                <td><form:errors path="birthDay"/> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label>
                <td><form:input path="age" type = "number"/> </td>
                <td><form:errors path="age"></form:errors> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr> 
                <td><form:label path="gender">Gender</form:label></td>
                <td><form:select path="gender">
                        <form:options items="${allgender}" itemLabel="gender"/>

                    </form:select></td>
                <td><form:errors path="gender"></form:errors></td>
            </tr>





            <tr><td colspan="3"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form:form> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Here file User.java

```
package edu.java.spring.service.user.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
@Entity
//@Table(name = "user",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="username")})
public class User {
//  @Column(name = "gender", nullable = false)
//  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
//  @Id
//  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
//  @Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
//  @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    public String getPassWord() {
        return passWord;
    }
    public void setPassWord(String passWord) {
        this.passWord = passWord;
    }
//  @Column(name = "birthday", nullable = false)
    public Date getBirthDay() {
        return birthDay;
    }

    public void setBirthDay(Date birthDay) {
        this.birthDay = birthDay;
    }
//  @Column(name="age", nullable = false)
    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    private String userName;
    private String passWord;
    private Date birthDay;
    private Integer age;
    private Gender gender;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring cannot convert a request parameter string into an object that contains the date (and time) information to `java.util.Date` object.

Becaue Spring doesn't know how to convert your date string to Date object because date format may vary depending on the locale

Spring has [CustomDateEditor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/CustomDateEditor.html) to convert this for you. You just need to register your date format.

You should register your Date formats using @InitBinder

```
 @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yourdateformat"); //yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ example
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));
    }
```

Comment: @DatB.Pham You could post that as answer, to help others when they face similar problem